# ¿Cómo puedo sumar un solo Diff y que lo muestre con pantalla?

Tags: php, html5

¿Cómo puedo sumar en **x variable** la resta entre las horas, que hago?

```
$dteDiff = ??????;  // <-- no sé cómo definirlo aquí

$dt2 = new DateTime($row["HE"]);
$dt3 = new DateTime($row["T_t"]);
$date = $dt2->diff($dt3);
echo $date->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

¿Se puede hacer con add, ya que es lo sugerido que he visto?

Answer (score 0):

Repliqué tu código de esta forma (poniendo una fecha manual) y dejándote un ejemplo de add:

```
<?php
$dt2 = new DateTime("2022-05-12 14:00:00");
$dt3 = new DateTime("2022-05-13 14:32:20");
$date = $dt2->diff($dt3);

$diferencia_dias=$date->days . ' dias '; #DIFERENCIA EN DIAS
$diferencia_horas=$date->format('%H:%I:%S').' horas'; #DIFERENCIA EN HORAS

echo 'Diferencia de: '.$dteDiff = $diferencia_dias.$diferencia_horas;  
echo "<br>";

#$nuevaFecha = new DateTime('2022-05-14 16:05:00');
$nuevaFecha = new DateTime('2022-05-13 16:25:00');

$nuevaFecha->add($date);
echo $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Buen aporte, gracias.  Solo que tengo un error, ya que la sumatoria comienza en 23:59, luego de inicializar con 00:00:00, a que se debe?